# Is there any side-effect when using addEventListener to handle paste event in IE browser?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, copy-paste

Recently, I've met a problem with IE browser that I can't reproduce on my browser. It's only happened in fixed computer (with a particular version, I guess so). 
I'm customizing copy function and using pure paste function of OS to paste the content.
The problem I've figured out is when I add these code

```
document.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    if (isIE()) {
        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", window.clipboardData.getData("Text").replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')); //FOR IE
    }
}); 
///(using to handle the problem of break lines in IE when paste event is triggered)
```

Sometimes, paste function of OS didn't work well. Sometimes, it could. It pasted empty content. However, I debugged that the clipboardData content was still remained. If I remove addEventListener event, everything works well. But, I need to keep the handling of break lines in IE, too.
Have anybody ever experienced this problem? Please help, thank you.

Comment: IE has been a pain for ages. Specially IE8. My suggestion, start by checking the compatibility of everything that you are using, if you really need to fix it

Comment: Excuse me, I'm a newbie. So could you show me more details about how to check the compatibility. Because it's a remote computer that I can't touch. I just know that it's happened in IE11 with version 11.1685.16299.0CO

Comment: As said, not all browsers share same features. Following is the compatibility of paste event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't understand that I used window.clipboardData.setData() in my customized copy function. And it worked well with IE11 in my computer or another computer, including the fixed computer that met the problem. Only addEventListener triggered the problem when added.

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but *format* of DataTransfer.getData and .setData should be lower-cased (specs ask the browsers to lower-case the input, but given IE's implementation was made before the specs, they may very well not have implemented that rule). So try with `"text"` instead of `"Text"`.

Comment: @Kaiido I've tried to output the content, and I've figure out it doesn't matter. When I pasted the second time, the clipboard content was exactly the text that I used setData to set before. So I think that clipboard still worked. But, it still pasted the empty string to the Input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have to assign the text to the Input value instead of using pure paste event of OS.
IE11 doesn't support much for the Input element at this point.

```
document.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    if (isIE()) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var content = window.clipboardData.getData("text").replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ''); //FOR IE
        var replace, position = e.target.selectionEnd - e.target.selectionStart;
        // if the position is the end of the string
        if (e.target.selectionStart === $(e.target).val().length)
            replace = $(e.target).val() + content;
        else replace = $(e.target).val().replace($(e.target).val().substr(e.target.selectionStart, position), content);

        $(e.target)
            .val(replace)
            // Manually trigger events if you want
            .trigger('input')
            .trigger('change');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems that you have already found the workaround, congratulation! I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.^_^

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code, it works well in IE11, Edge and Chrome browser:

```
<div class="source" contenteditable="true">Try copying text from this box...</div>
<div class="target" contenteditable="true">...and pasting it into this one</div>
<script> 
    var target = document.querySelector('div.target');
    target.addEventListener('paste', function (event) {
        var paste = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
        paste = paste.toUpperCase();
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (!selection.rangeCount) return false;
        selection.deleteFromDocument();
        selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(paste));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

IE11 Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it can't work in my case. window.getSelection().rangeCount is always 0 when I try to paste to the Input element. I met a problem like this one: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/documentgetselection-not-working-properly-inside/9daf34d7-69b4-4077-ac55-5890d0b787ae